# Comparing value in a variable with value of a text field

Tags: java, variables

I have a variable in a class `X`, i want to match its content with the value of a field in another class `Y`.
i have the following code in class `X`:

```
String Cellresult;
Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(columNumber,rowNumber); // gets the contents of the cell of a an excell sheet
Cellresult = a1.getContents();    // stores the values in the variable named Cellresult
System.out.println(Cellresult);   // prints the values which is working fine till here
```

Now in another class `Y` , i want to compare the value of `Cellresult` with the value of an already filled field that has id `txtVFNAME`.

I tried:

```
WebElement a = idriver.findElement(By.id("txtVFNAME"));
if (a.equals(Cellresult)){
       System.out.println("text is equal");

};
```

I am getting error even before compiling that ::`Cellresult cannot be resolved to a variable`.
 I am using java, Eclipse, IE 10 , win 8.kindly help. many thanks.

Comment: `Cellresult` is known only in `X` class, make a *getter* and use it in `Y` class. Please note that your naming is very confusing. I advise you to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: how can i access it in another class?

Comment: and also.. your Cellresult is a local variable.. it wont be visible outside the function.. You have to make it a instance level variable in class X (put it outside all functions but inside the class), add getter and setter to it.. and in class Y you have to create a new instance of X, use getCellResult() to get result..

Comment: Either you make `String Cellresult;` as instance variable and public or add method that return `Cellresult` value from your class `X` to class `Y`.

Comment: And please, do not capitalize the name of a variable... It looks like the name of a class

Comment: thank you all. thanks for the help. I am really grateful to all of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just refer a variable of Class `X` in Class `Y`. To be able to access an instance variable of Class `X`, create an instance of that access it using that.

```
X x = new X();
if (a.equals(x.Cellresult)){ // Cellresult is public
```

But in your case it seems that `Cellresult` is present inside a method and not as an instance variable. In that case, return your `Cellresult` from the method and use it here.

```
X x = new X();
if (a.equals(x.methodThatReturnsCellresult())){ // methodThatReturnsCellresult is public
```

The method in your Class `X` would look like this.

```
public String methodThatReturnsCellresult() {
    // Other stuffs too.
    String Cellresult;
    Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(columNumber,rowNumber); // gets the contents of the cell of a an excell sheet
    Cellresult = a1.getContents();    // stores the values in the variable named Cellresult
    System.out.println(Cellresult);  
    return Cellresult; // returning the Cellresult value to be used elsewhere, in your case, in Class Y
}
```